# .NET XMPP/Jabber against Openfire Server for getting XML Stream messages

Tags: .net, xmpp, openfire

I'm lokking for .NET open source library to subscribe to Openfire server to get XML stream messages (not chat messages).

To be clear: XMPP clients like Pidgin have usually plugin named "XMPP Console" the get XML stream from the remote XMPP server.
How do i get it in Jabber-NET or S22.Xmpp components?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In open source XMPP client like [S22.Xmpp](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Xmpp) you can add stanza message event and get those events.